# Converter string Base16 (Hexadecimal) para Base10 (Decimal)

Tags: c#, .net, conversão-de-tipo, hexadecimal

Tenho a seguinte string `"615769EF"`, que está em hexadecimal.

Como convertê-la para base10 e que o resultado seja a string `"01633118703"` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
string hex = "615769EF";

int decValue = int.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Para decimal seria assim:

```
string hex = "615769EF";

decimal decValue = decimal.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Mas ocorre o seguinte erro:

> Não há suporte para o estilo de número AllowHexSpecifier em tipos de dados de ponto flutuante.

Mas convertendo para `int` ele retornará o resultado `1633118703` sem o `0` na frente. Aí se quiser em formato de `string` só fazer um `ToString`;

Exemplo:

```
string hex = "615769EF";

string decValue = int.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber).ToString();
```

Answer (score 5):

Achei uma [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/923814/396200) interessante que me levou ao uso de  `Convert.ToUInt64(valor,fromBase)`.

Esse segundo parâmetro `fromBase` permite conversão para base 2, 8, 10, e 16.

```
//Hexadecimal para Decimal
string cpfHexadecimal = "615769EF";

string cpfDecimal = Convert.ToUInt64(cpfHexadecimal,16).ToString("00000000000");
```

Convert.ToString também tem esse segundo parâmetro.

Exemplo:

```
//Decimal para Hexadecimal
cpfDecimal = "01633118703";
cpfHexadecimal = Convert.ToString(long.Parse(cpfDecimal),16);
```

Eis um exemplo que criei no https://dotnetfiddle.net/jXJvLZ